# Wrong size of ggvis plot in interactive R Markdown

Tags: r, plot, shiny, r-markdown, ggvis

I am trying to add an interactive ggvis plot in an interactive R Markdown file. It works fine, except that the size of the plot is bigger than the assigned space and I always get a "cut" plot and rolling bar. I tried chunk options (out.height and fig.height) or ggvis set_options without sucess. Below is an example.
Thanks

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  ggvis(~ x_, ~ count_/sum(count_), fill = ~am) %>%
  compute_bin(~mpg, width = input_slider(min = 1, max = 10)) %>%
    layer_bars(stack = FALSE, opacity := 0.5) %>%
  add_axis("x", title = "mpg", grid = FALSE) %>%
  add_axis("y", title = "Proportion", grid = FALSE, format = "%")
```
````